# Can't Delete StorageFolder inside the Appdata folder

Tags: c#, uwp

```
var folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync("Thumbnails");
await folder.DeleteAsync();
```

Gives me:

- $exception  {"Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"} System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Can't figure out why I can't delete this.  I wrote a recursion method to try and clear out each file inside each subfolder first and the removing said folder.  Some of the files would delete but others would not.

Comment: `DeleteAsync` presumably calls [RemoveDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365488.aspx). This API call only succeeds, if the following conditions are met: *"This path must specify an empty directory, and the calling process must have delete access to the directory."* In your question you note, that some of the files would not delete, so that makes the API call fail (although I don't know if this would fail with error code `E_ACCESSDENIED`). Also note, that a directory must not contain any other directories (even if empty) when it gets removed.

Comment: Thanks I'll review my recursion method.  Is there not an easier way to remove a folder from the file system that isn't empty?

Comment: I doubt there isn't. If there was, the Shell wouldn't have had to implement their own (see [SHFileOperation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164.aspx)). I guess it's just not *that* easy to write a specification for this API. What should happen in case of links/junctions? How should you deal with infinite recursions due to links/junctions? What should happen if the operation fails halfway through? A lot of questions that needed to be addressed.

Comment: Thanks again.  The issue has been fully resolved.  The reason some files weren't deleting was because they were still in memory.  A manual GC.Collect() before trying to delete them solved it.

Comment: It's usually better to go with the [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx), so that resources are deterministically disposed off, and manually triggering a garbage collection cycle isn't needed. Regardless, you should wrap your previous comment into an answer for future visitors. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if that feels awkward to you.

Comment: It's an image file bound to a UI element in XAML so a using statement wouldn't make sense.  Your first response is the answer.  Folders must be empty before they can be removed, and there is no alternative method.  Copy and paste it as an answer and I will mark it so.